# Can I add a 'service entrance barrier' to a QOC electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a Square D QOC series main panel (QOC 40MW225). I'd like to add service entrance barriers to this panel - the plastic covers which protect from accidental contact with the connection lugs of the main service entrance cable. I take it that newer panels these days typically come with a barrier, but mine is old enough not to have one.

It seems like the Square D *PKSB1HA* might be the correct product for this panel, but I'd like to confirm that. e.g., some [marketing text](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-100-Amp-225-Amp-Service-Entrance-Barriers-PKSB1HACP/311790748) for this product says:

> Compatible in 100 through 225 amp Homeline & QO S0 series panels
>
> Retrofittable to most existing Square D load centers

Is that the correct barrier or is there an alternative?

Photo of the relevant portion of my panel:

[image]

(I didn't do any of that wiring myself - its a full 40 space panel including a number of tandem breakers)

Comment: Do you have pictures?

Comment: @Ecnerwal were you thinking of pictures of the lugs inside the panel? Or some other detail?

Comment: @Ecnerwal added a photo of the lug area

Comment: This is a shopping question because you are asking which barrier to buy.  Further, it's specialty knowledge that's best gotten from a Square D dealer.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I don't know if I agree... it certainly started out as an "is X compatible with Y" question. Since it is the case that X and Y are incompatible, maybe the only remaining useful information would be if some other product Z could work. But I think that's almost certainly not the case from the available info.

Answer (score 6):

PKSB1HA will definitely not fit a QOC 40MW225 panel, and probably not any QOC series panel.

They have an [FAQ](https://www.se.com/us/en/faqs/FA109001/) which says:

> Does Schneider Electric offer repair parts for the Old(25+years) QO
> Load centers? (For example old QO--MG200_ _ , QO--MW200_ _ or
> QOBW3150-1)
>
> *No, the older 25+ years or so QO load centers are all obsolete, with no repair parts available. Consider replacing the complete load center
> with a current design*

That was discouraging but still a bit vague, since I wasn't looking for "repair parts".  I emailed SD to ask about the barrier specifically and they replied basically just citing the same FAQ. I decided to just try the PKSB1HA and see.

**It absolutely does not fit**. With the panel open (*) a visual inspection made this clear - the main issue is that the two lugs are much too close together so that the two legs of the barrier overlap considerably. There may be some other dimensions that also would prevent a fit even if that were not the case.

This still leaves open the very slight possibility that some other product could exist, but that seems to be very unlikely.

---

<sub>(*) I had taken precautions with the cover off including wearing 1000V rubber gloves with protective leather outers, and of course having the main breaker off to limit potential 'hot' contact points.</sub>

Comment: Excellent advice from Square D: Replace with a modern ***Eaton*** panel.  Or simply one of [Eaton's retrofit interior kits](https://www.eaton.com/ecm/groups/public/@pub/@electrical/documents/content/sa00406001e.pdf) so you don't have to tear the box out of the wall.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I guess I can't blame them for going for the upsell.

Answer (score 3):

**An** alternative (better than nothing since they don't make a part to do it nicely) is to apply good quality electrical tape (not some off-brand that falls off after a few months) *very carefully* to cover the service lugs (not touching them, but taped over the the black plastic wings around them.)

Personal bias - pick a bright color, not black. Black blends into the rest of the black plastic. A visual cue that this spot is different and to be avoided is not a bad thing.